# join x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

While joining the centos 7 node to cluster 1.9.0, `kubeadm join` command gives this error message.

`Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://10.10.10.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid]`

I got this message last night, this morning when run this command it worked.  I removed and trying to create the cluster this morning, again its giving same error message.

```
kubeadm join --token f115fe.f0eea05182abe63a 10.10.10.10:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:48d4dc90a08ff73a0cfc63e30a313aaf1903fd51da8f9ce4cc79f95ce529b8d1

[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://10.10.10.10:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https://10.10.10.10:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://10.10.10.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid]
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://10.10.10.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid]
```

How to resolve this error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is my node didn't have the correct time. after configuring NTP service node was able to join the master.

Comment: I had different ntp source on master and worker node. Once I sync'd both master and worker to same ntp source then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installed a docker repository with a new certificate. When connecting from the a command line using docker I was able to push and pull the image but kubernetes generated an error 'x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid'. When I connected to the minikube VM 'ssh minikube' and entered 'date' I noticed the clock was several hours off. When I manually set the date in the minikube VM the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem might be outdated certificate.
In case of microk8s reinstalling worked for me.
More here: https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1150.

Answer (score 0):

With AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services), follow link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation

Only needs run the command

```
az aks rotate-certs -g $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -n $CLUSTER_NAME
```